# How do modify the inclusion/exclusion behavior of Boundary values in the Range function?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples, range

**Part1:**
I have a dictionary as:

```
mydict = {'K': {'VAL1': 'apple', 'VAL2': (60, 80)},
          'L': {'VAL1': 'mango', 'VAL2': (90, 100)},
          'M': {'VAL1': 'pears', 'VAL2': (120, 150)}}

rto = tuple(range(60,80))    # works
rto = tuple(range(mydict['K']['VAL2']))
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

How do I make this work, i wana iterate through the dictionary ??

**Part2:**
Assuming the above can work, I want to check if a value is in the range:

```
my_value = 70        
rto = tuple(range(60,80))
if my_value in rto :
    print("Value is in range")
else:
    print("Value not in range")

# Output:   
# 70- Value is in range  
# 20- Value not in range  
# 60- Value is in range  
# 80- Value not in range  
# (This tells me that the range function includes 60 and excludes 80 from the 
# test)
```

How can I manipulate the boundary conditions for the test? Meaning either:
Include both 60 and 80.
Exclude both 60 or 80.
Include either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a range, since you can run a check between the values to get your solution.

The code below uses the less than and greater than operator to find if the my_value exists between the tuples:

```
 for i in [j['VAL2'] for i,j in mydict.items()]:
    if i[0] <= my_value <= i[-1]:
        print(f'{i},{my_value} value is in range')
    else:
        print(f'{i},{my_value} value is not in range')
```

Comment: Yes, this works very well and is more concise code.

Is there any way to manipulate the boundary conditions though ? for example, currently for key 'K' , 80 shows not in range of (60,80). I want to show both 60 and 80 in range of (60,80)..

Comment: Changed the code to include a less than or equal to for the right boundary. so it should pick up both 60 and 80. lemme know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for the dict. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
rto = tuple(range(*mydict['K']['VAL2']))
```